# Visual studio 2017 code analyzer unit test can't load custom attribute from external assembly

Tags: visual-studio-2017, analyzer, roslyn-code-analysis

Under visual studio 2017, creating an extension using Analyzer with code fix template. For code analyzer unit test code, it can't parse custom attribute in external DLL. It shows ErrorType `NameSpace.MyCustomAttribute` for `attr.AttributeClass`

The external DLL is targeting dot.net 4.6. I added the MetaReference through

```
.AddMetadataReference(projectId, ExternalDllReference);
```

The ExternalDLLReference is loaded through

```
MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(MyAttribute).Assembly.Location)
```

I also tried to manually load the assembly through fixed location. Same result.

The unit test c# code is pretty simple. For custom attribute defined in the unit test string, it loads correctly. It is just the attribute in the external DLL not loaded correctly.

I tried similar attribute (TestMethod defined in test framework) which has the same result so it doesn't look it is unique to my custom DLL.

```
var test = @"
using System;
using MyCustom.Attributes;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{ 
    public class Custom2Attribute : Attribute
    {
    }

    [Custom2]
    [DataSynchronizationContract(ClientSynchronizationMode.AllowClientChanges, DatabaseSynchronizationMode.Automatic)] 
    public class TestClass
    {   
        [DataSynchronizationMember]
        [Custom2]
        public string PatientID { get; set; } 

        [DataSynchronizationMember(Client = ClientSynchronizationMode.DenyClientChanges, Database = DatabaseSynchronizationMode.NotSynchronized)]
        public string OrderID { get; set; } 
    }
}";
```

The "Custom2Attribute" is parsed correctly. But `DataSynchronizationContract` and `DataSynchronizationMember` (defined in the external DLL) are parsed as ErrorType for `attr.AttributeClass`

This is the error I get:

> ((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.NamedTypeSymbol)attr.AttributeClass).DefaultMarshallingCharSet'
>   threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException

Comment: This is the error - '((Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Symbols.NamedTypeSymbol)attr.AttributeClass).DefaultMarshallingCharSet' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' I got through visual studio watch window